# Why can't i click on "Draw Curve" in Blender 2.78

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

i recently installed blender 2.78, and when i tried to use the newly added feature "Draw Curve" i can't, i can't click on it, it appears to be in grey.
Does anyone knows why, and thanks in advanced.[image: Her it is]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried some stuff and it and it seems like it doesn't generate a new object (a curve).

It did work after i added a Bezier curve myself. After adding a curve i just went to the toolshlef and was ready to use it to align the curve with my drawn curve

Comment: Yep - got to add a curve before you can draw a curve - sure there is some logic in that (?). Once you have created a curve you can delete the vertices/ control points and then you can really draw a curve from scratch :)

Answer (score 1):

Just found out.

You need to create a curve first. Then SHIFT+A to draw a curve.